# how to clean up useEffect when using setInterval and fetch?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, jsx, setinterval, react-functional-component

I tried so many options but nothing seems to solve the problem. I keep getting the warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component". I am new at programming so the solucion might be very easy for you. I've tried setting a variable inside the useEffect in order to know whether the component is mounted or not and only updates the state if the value of the variable is true and then setting the value to false inside the return function. I also tried using abortController but both cases did not work for me. Here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CircularGraphs from "./CircularGraphs";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";

function Statistic(props) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const getData = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3009/statistic`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === "") {
      setLoading(true);
      getData();
    } else {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        getData();
      }, 5000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div
      className={
        props.activeItem === 2 ? "second-item show" : "second-item hidden"
      }
    >
      <div className="sidebar-right-expanded-title">
        <h6>Estadistica</h6>
        <h5 className="sidebar-right-expanded-sucursal">Matriz</h5>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="graph-container">
            <div className="day-graph-container">
              <CircularGraphs percentage={data.today ? data.today : 50} />
              <p>NV-día</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="day-month-graph-container">
            <div className="previousday-graph-container">
              <CircularGraphs
                percentage={data.previousDay ? data.previousDay : 50}
              />
              <p>NV-día anterior</p>
            </div>
            <div className="month-graph-container">
              <CircularGraphs percentage={data.month ? data.month : 50} />
              <p>NV-mes</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Statistic;
```

Comment: Define the getData inside the useEffect itself.

Comment: Already tried that and still getting the warning

Answer (score 0):

So I'll try to help by telling what I do in those cases:

1. `const [data, setData] = useState("");` don't make the default state as empty string instead make a mock if u already know the object that u gonna receive something like

   ```
   const [data, setData] = useState({today: 50, previousDay: 50, month: 50});
   ```
2. For the lodaer you can set the loader in getData so u know that the loader will start when getData is called and it stops when u have the response or the error and you can make the interval directly without testing since you want the data every 5 sec
3. You can use setTimout if you want the getData fire once so you don't need to clean the timer
4. If you want the getData to be called every 5 seconds, you should do the cleanup I guess you should do return clearInterval(interval); (I'm not sure)

Comment: I tried what you told me but nothing, i used another useEffect as ComponentDidMount where i can get the data the first time and that's what causes the warning to show. The other useEffect as ComponentWillUnmount where i clear the interval because i need the data to be update every 5 sec.

Comment: Btw how bad is to ignore that warning?

Comment: Oh another thing put an empty array on useEffecr as the second argument cuz u kinda tell rect go over the useEffect whenever data changes so that might be a solution. Another thing componentwillUnmount is no longer a good practice said facebook. And for ignoring the warnings dont do that make it clean its better always and u find lot of stuff in the process ;)